# Where is cups-pdf.ppd file?

Tags: cups, ubuntu-22.04

I need to make some tests in .ppd file. I haven't a printer so I install CUPS-PDF to print to .pdf file.
But I can't find a current .ppd file (cups-pdf.ppd).
What I tried already (after simply search in file system:)):

```
$ /usr/lib/cups/driver/openprinting-ppds list | grep 'CUPS-PDF'
```

but it returned no result.

P.S. Why I think that I need cups-pdf.ppd? When I print a document and add cover page "Form" (where "Secret", "Top secret", etc), in section "Driver" I see CUPS-PDF.PPD

P.P.S. Maybe you know another way to work and test .ppd file without printer. I would appreciate any advice on this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in directory `/etc/cups/ppd`.